# Почему срабатывает конвертер значений при вызове команды на кнопке?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть 2 такие кнопки:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource CustomButton}" FontSize="16" Content="Провести работу над ошибками" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="20, 10" Margin="0, 0, 7, 0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tickets, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource NullList}}" Command="{Binding DoWorkAtMistakes}"/>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource CustomButton}" FontSize="16" Content="Пройти тестирование снова" Padding="20, 10" Command="{Binding StartTestingAgain}" />
```

К одной из них я задал значение для `Button.Visibility` как `{Binding ElementName=tickets, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource NullList}}`. *Идея* этого конвертера состоит в том, что я передаю ему список (`ItemsControl.ItemsSource`), а он считывает значение его свойства `Count` или если оно равно "**0**", то он возвращает `Visibility.Collapsed`. Вот его код:

```
class EmptyListToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object list, Type type, object param, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (((ICollection)list).Count == 0) return Visibility.Collapsed;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object obj, Type type, object param, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Также к этим кнопкам привязаны команды.

Проблема в том, что если кнопке задана команда, то при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает конвертер и у меня вылетает `Exception` по типу "Переданный объект равен `null`".

---

Это было раз. А вот и второй.

Если первой кнопке задан этот конвертер, то при нажатии на вторую кнопку он **также** срабатывает (у второй кнопки нет конвертера) и также вылетает ошибка. Почему?

**Почему конвертер для `Visibility` срабатывает когда не должен этого делать?**

Comment: так а в чем проблема сделать проверку на null в вашем конвертере? По вопросу: может вы меняете значение коллекции, которая привязана к свойству визибилити?

Comment: @pashagoroshko, нет не меняю. **Проблема** в том, что я не знаю почему он срабатывает когда не должен (он ведь должен срабатывать только при установке/смене значения для `Visibility`).

Comment: нет, он будет срабатывать когда ваша коллекция будет меняется. Что скажете по первому вопросу? мне кажется, это более правильно, что нужно сделать для начала, а уже потом разбираться с остальным

Comment: @pashagoroshko, я сделал проверку как вы и посоветовали. Всё работает, как и ожидалось). Спасибо!